# XrmServiceContext object is not getting the latest data from CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrm

i have a wcf which connects to crm (on prem) to retrieve an account record. i can see when the entity is retrieved it does not hold the current record i.e. some field will still hold the old column value. i tried with various merge option with no avail. please see the code below

```
using (XrmServiceContext cContext = new XrmServiceContext(con))
{                
    Entity ent = cContext.Retrieve(ConstantKVP.AccountSchema.ENTITY_LOGICAL_NAME, AccountId, new ColumnSet(true));
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Ensure that the data you are trying to change is being saved, the context will access the database values. If you make changes in the UI without saving these new values will not be persisted to the database

Comment: i think i did not explain my self correctly... the data is saved directly in crm using crm form. the wcf retrieves the date after that but still it keeps on the previous value of the fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible the data is being cached?

`cContext.TryAccessCache(cache => cache.Mode = OrganizationServiceCacheMode.Disabled);`

I took this approach for a `CrmOrganizationServiceContext`, so perhaps the same theory applies.

Comment: i already changed the code so that it uses early bound org service proxy. the code look much cleaner (and dare i say faster) with significant changes on the data model. but +1 for the answer anyway...

Answer (score 0):

After save use clear changes `cContext.ClearChanges();`

For retrieves use `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges`

Or

Create a new XrmServiceContext object by passing a newed up organizationservice:

```
var uncachedOrganizationService = new OrganizationService("Xrm");
var uncachedXrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext(uncachedOrganizationService);
var ent = uncachedXrmServiceContext.Retrieve(ConstantKVP.AccountSchema.ENTITY_LOGICAL_NAME,AccountId,new ColumnSet(true));
```

Comment: sorry but the first solution did not work.. the second one seems to be a bit redundant.. i tried with quick a console application and it seems using organizationserviceproxy does not come up with this problem. but that means saying good bye to early bound classes.

Comment: i am not attaching the object because exist. i am just selecting the record for the very first time...

Comment: Can you update your web config in your post? Esp. the XrmService portion of things? If it happens on first fetch too, did you also try `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges`? Also do you have any caching related config elements in your web.config?

Comment: i tried with all the merge option. the config portion for you,<microsoft.xrm.client>
    <contexts>
      <add name="Xrm" type="Xrm.XrmServiceContext, SCV"/>
    </contexts>
  </microsoft.xrm.client>